# What is the WebMvcConfigurationSupport replacement in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, content-negotiation

In traditional Spring MVC, I can extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and do the following:

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
    favorParameter(true).
    defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
    mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
}
```

How do I do this in a Spring Boot app? My understanding is that adding a `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` with `@EnableWebMvc` will disable the Spring Boot WebMvc autoconfigure, which I don't want.

Answer (score 9):

Per Spring Boot reference on [auto configuration and Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-auto-configuration):

> If you want to take complete control of Spring MVC, you can add your own @Configuration annotated with @EnableWebMvc. If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features, and you just want to add additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view controllers etc.) you can add your own @Bean of type WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but without @EnableWebMvc.

For example if you want to keep Spring Boot's auto configuration, and  customize ContentNegotiationConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   ...
   @Override
   public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
      super.configureContentNegotiation(configurer);
      configurer.favorParameter(..);
      ...
      configurer.defaultContentType(..);
   }
}
```

Comment: You're right and I knew that but the class I'm currently extending is not `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` but `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`. The later provides configuration options the former doesn't.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to use any part of Spring Boot's WebMvcAutoConfiguration and provide your own WebMvcConfigurationSupport as Spring Boot will only auto configure if there's no WebMvcConfigurationSupport. I think one of the advantages of using Spring Boot is the auto configuration. I would try to use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, and for options that are NOT supported use some sort of BeanPostProcessor to customize it manually.

Comment: I'll try that. Since your answer is not exactly what I was looking for, I'm not accepting it now but I'll upvote it. If this works out, I'll later accept your answer.

Comment: Hi @ikumen I've tried this configuration, but my other MVC configuration is XML base, so I am getting this error:  _Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [com/ecc/ws/rest/config/WebConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set_

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring 5.0 you can use the interface WebMvcConfigurer since Java 8 allows for default implementations on interfaces.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   ...
   @Override
   public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.favorParameter(..);
      ...
      configurer.defaultContentType(..);
   }
}
```